# and condition in ternary operator not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a custom button built by MUI to my project. I want to enable my button if 2 objects are not empty, otherwise the button remains disabled. I have written code that is working half correctly.

I want to only enable my button if 2 condition satisfies. But the button becomes enabled only when one condition meets the criteria. The ternary operation is not accepting the && condition.

How can I tackle this problem?

```
{Object.keys(userSelectDevicename).length === 0 && Object.keys(userSelectDevicecategory).length === 0 ? (
  <>
    {" "}
    <WsButton type="submit" size="small" variant="contained" disabled={bool}>
      Add
    </WsButton>
  </>
) : (
  <>
    {" "}
    <WsButton type="submit" size="small" variant="contained" disabled={!bool}>
      Add
    </WsButton>
  </>
)};
```

Comment: Wrap the condition inside a parentheses `(`. Like `(Object.keys(userSelectDevicename).length === 0 && Object.keys(userSelectDevicecategory).length === 0) ? `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two identical JSX in each case. The changing factor is `disabled={!bool}`. You can use ternary operator for this, but I would do something different, like below. To make the code cleaner. Which is to create a function that returns the disabled boolean state of the button.

```
export default function YourComponent(){

   function getBool(){
      let lengthOne = Object.keys(userSelectDevicename).length
      let lenghtTwo = Object.keys(userSelectDevicecategory).length

      if(lengthOne === 0 && lengthTwo === 0) return true
      else return false
   }
     
   return(
      <>
       {" "}
       <WsButton type="submit" size="small" variant="contained" disabled={!getBool()}>
          Add
       </WsButton>
      </>
   ) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add both conditions inside small brackets. `&&` works as a conditional operator first and will only check the `Object.keys(userSelectDevicename).length === 0` first only if its true based on it. It will run the 2nd half. That is the code from `Object.keys(userSelectDevicecategory).length === 0) ? ....`

when adding the brackets brackets priority will be more and the condition will be evaluated as a whole and then the ternary operator will kick in based on result of the conditions.

```
 {(Object.keys(userSelectDevicename).length === 0 && Object.keys(userSelectDevicecategory).length === 0) ? (
                          <>
                            {" "}
                            <WsButton type="submit" size="small" variant="contained" disabled={bool}>
                              Add
                            </WsButton>
                          </>
                        ) : (
                          <>
                            {" "}
                            <WsButton type="submit" size="small" variant="contained" disabled={!bool}>
                              Add
                            </WsButton>
                          </>
                        )}
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: I believe this is the correct way could you try adding a minimum reproducible example to have a look?

Comment: Also, the only difference in those two buttons is the disabled property which has `bool` written inside and we don't know what that is. Do you even need a ternary there if you just want to make the button disabled depending on the value of the `bool` variable?

Comment: bool carrying true